# Wxpython Radio Button Preselected

Tags: python, user-interface, radio-button, wxpython

I have 3 wxpython radio buttons.  When run, the first button (Value A) is already selected.  How do I make it so no buttons are selected initially?

```
    self.rb1 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Value A', (50, 10), style=wx.RB_GROUP)
    self.rb2 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Value B', (10, 30))
    self.rb3 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Value C', (10, 50))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetVal, id=self.rb1.GetId())
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetVal, id=self.rb2.GetId())
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetVal, id=self.rb3.GetId())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RB_GROUP` it makes buttons mutually exclusive and the first button is always checked. So if you check one this will uncheck the other. If you don't need this mutually exclusive buttons then you can use `RB_SINGLE` for each of your buttons. See [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/RadioButton.html) the docs.

**HINT**

Maybe a workaround would perhaps be to create a hidden radio-button, which would be selected on creation of the group.

Comment: i noticed even if multiple `RadioButton` groups are created and you do `rb.SetValue(False)` on each of them and on each of their items, then the very first radiobutton in the very first group created still has an initial value; and yes, simply creating a single hidden radiobutton group with just 1 item solves the issue